# Open url in browser instead of activity when Firebase notification is tapped - Android

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use this code (see below **#The Code that I use**) working to open specific activity when Firebase Notification is tapped. Instead of opening specific activity, I want the Firebase Notification to open browser and go to that specific link.

I use Firebase Console in sending notification. I want to use this custom data.

```
Key: url
Value: www.randomurl.com
```

Please see the code below and help me achieve opening url in browser instead of opening my App.

#### #The Code that I use.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessageService";
Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");

    String imageUri = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");

    String TrueOrFalse = remoteMessage.getData().get("JournalActivity");

    //To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
    bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(imageUri);

    sendNotification(message, bitmap, TrueOrFalse);
}

private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Bitmap image, String TrueOrFalse) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("JournalActivity", TrueOrFalse);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo_new)
            .setContentTitle(messageBody)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                    .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}

public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return bitmap;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
}
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In your pendingIntent,pass this intent.

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Hi @Karandeep, I want the URLs to be different depending on the notification. Let's say I will send the notification and the url today is fashion.com, tomorrow i will send a new notification and sports.com will be the url.

Comment: you can parse the data same way your other keys.(image, message etc)

Comment: Sorry my bad. but I just copied the code I use from some website and I have just few understanding what's happening there. Can you help me where to put it there? thanks

Comment: Any luck finding the solution?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to pass the url into your sendNotification method. To do this, add the following line in OnMessageReceived under String Message:

```
String url = remoteMessage.getData().get("url");
```

Then, pass url to your sendNotification method. Add url to the last line in onMessageReceived:

```
sendNotification(message, bitmap, TrueOrFalse, url);
```

Next, accept the url in your sendNotification method. Add url to your method header like this:

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Bitmap image, String TrueOrFalse, String url)
```

Finally, add this under your intent in sendNotification:

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
```

This will cause the notification to open your link in the browser when it is clicked.

Comment: Where would I put this intent? Will i replace my current intent or add that below my current one?

Comment: You don't need to create a new intent, you can just add the second line below your current one.

Comment: You mean onMessageReceived i will add this: String imageUri = remoteMessage.getData().get("url"); 

Then on sendNotification. I will change the Intent Main Activity to Intent.ACTION_VIEW? + i will add your second line?

Comment: No, I think you should leave onMessageReceived the same and just add the second line in sendNotification

Comment: Hi! I have followed your instruction but there's an error. The word remoteMessage turns red.